# Is there a Keypass plugin for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keepass

A Google search is inconclusive.

Comment: Alternatively you could dump the Keypass database in your Dropbox and sync it through there ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - It is already in my dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

As a former user of Keypass, let me say that LastPass for Chrome is just as good, if not better than Keypass. The best part is that you can import your Keypass database to LastPass for the ultimate 1-2 punch.

http://lastpass.com/

Comment: I love using Lastpass, though off course Keypass has a desktop version that works very nicely...

Comment: Hmmm ... something tells me that it's not: http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-20060464-83.html  When your primary product is security, and you don't deliver, you have failed.

Comment: @Dan How did they fail in that instance? There was no intrusion and they only reported what they observed to play it safe. Not to mention that they used it as an opportunity to upgrade their security.

Comment: "Siegrist explained that he doesn't think a lot of data would've been hacked, but just enough to capture a small number of user names and passwords. Though the passwords were in an encrypted format, those combined with the usernames could give hackers enough of a starting point to hunt for accounts with weak master passwords." I'm not sure why that's not considered "an intrusion".  Not massive enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

I *love* Keepass, but I store my frequently used **website logins** with iMacros for Firefox and [iMacros for Chrome](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome) (free, open-source browser addons). It automates the complete login sequence (think of macro recorders for web browser).